# Woocommerce Add to cart link Ajax enabled in other post or pages

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

In Woocommerce, I Would like co create add to cart link on a simple page of WordPress website *(not product page)*.

So I have tried this code *(Where 123 is the product ID)*:

```
<a href="http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123">Buy</a>
```

I have enabled AJAX add to cart on archives pages Woocommerce option setting.

But It doesn't work and Ajax functionality is not enabled on my custom Add-to-cart link.

How to enable ajax add-to-cart on a custom link *(in other pages than woocommerce ones)*?

Comment: instead of `http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123` use `http://example.com/{your-current-page}/?add-to-cart=123`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To enable ajax in a custom add to cart button, there is 3 ways at least:

1. **A simple HTML Ajax add to cart link:**

   ```
   <a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=37" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="123" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
   ```
2. **Using Woocommerce existing `[add_to_cart id='123']` shortcode**  *(same usage than above)*
   [image][image]
3. **The most customizable: A custom shortcode without price included** *(customizable button text, additional classes, quantity and many others possibilities)*

   ```
   if( ! function_exists('custom_ajax_add_to_cart_button') && class_exists('WooCommerce') ) {
       function custom_ajax_add_to_cart_button( $atts ) {
           // Shortcode attributes
           $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
               'id' => '0', // Product ID
               'qty' => '1', // Product quantity
               'text' => '', // Text of the button
               'class' => '', // Additional classes
           ), $atts, 'ajax_add_to_cart' );

           if( esc_attr( $atts['id'] ) == 0 ) return; // Exit when no Product ID

           if( get_post_type( esc_attr( $atts['id'] ) ) != 'product' ) return; // Exit if not a Product

           $product = wc_get_product( esc_attr( $atts['id'] ) );

           if ( ! $product ) return; // Exit when if not a valid Product

           $classes = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
               'button',
               'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
               $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
               $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
           ) ) ).' '.$atts['class'];

           $add_to_cart_button = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" %s %s %s class="%s">%s</a>',
               esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
               'data-quantity="' . esc_attr( $atts['qty'] ) .'"',
               'data-product_id="' . esc_attr( $atts['id'] ) .'"',
               'data-product_sku="' . esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ) .'"',
               esc_attr( isset( $classes ) ? $classes : 'button' ),
               esc_html( empty( esc_attr( $atts['text'] ) ) ? $product->add_to_cart_text() : esc_attr( $atts['text'] ) )
           );

           return $add_to_cart_button;
       }
       add_shortcode('ajax_add_to_cart', 'custom_ajax_add_to_cart_button');
   }
   ```

   *This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.
   **USAGE:**
   In posts and pages text editor:

   ```
   [ajax_add_to_cart id='123' text='Buy']
   ```

   In PHP files or templates:

   ```
   echo do_shortcode( "[ajax_add_to_cart id='123' text='Buy']" );
   ```

   Inserted in HTML code on a php page:

   ```
   <?php echo do_shortcode( "[ajax_add_to_cart id='123' text='Buy']" ); ?>
   ```

   [image][image]

   > **Hide Ajax "view cart"**
   >   For custom shortcode, to hide the Ajax "view cart" behavior, **you can add in the code, before** `return $add_to_cart_button;` the following:
   >
   > ```
   > $style = '<style>a.added_to_cart.wc-forward { display:none !important; }</style>';
   >
   > $add_to_cart_button = $style . $add_to_cart_button ;
   > ```

---

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the `[add_to_cart]` Shortcode.

Simplest usage with the default parameters:

```
[add_to_cart id="123" /]
```

Disables the default style and hides the price:

```
[add_to_cart id="123" style="" show_price="false" /]
```

**See some sample output**
[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 1):

I used this for my plugin and it is working fine:

```
function wsb_add_to_cart_button( ) {
    global $product;

    $classes = implode( ' ',  array(
        'button',
        'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
    )  );

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( isset( $classes ) ? $classes : 'button' ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_type() ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        ),
    $product );
}
```

for showing button:

```
<?php echo wsb_add_to_cart_button(); ?>
```